# Need to read a stream from a URL, changing a "page" attribute in URI until it returns "No records found" string

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, xml-rpc

I have a C# .NET Core console app I'm working on to fetch data from a URL-RPC gateway. I can retrieve the data and write it to a file just fine--just having some trouble even getting started on the logic for incrementing the "page number" attribute in the URI I'm calling against until it returns no more data and the string "No records found." Each "page" of data is about 200 records, so I'll need to increment the page number in the URL until it returns that string.

Here's my basic code (this includes a console write line to verify for debugging purposes, I have other methods to write the data to a file later on.)

```
string rpcURL;
rpcURL = "https://api.myWebsite.com/urlrpc?method=getPlacementReport&username=" + userName + "&password=" + passWord + "&class_code=" + classCode + "&from_date=" + startDate + "&to_date=" + endDate + "&page_num=1";

Console.WriteLine(rpcURL);

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; Windows NT 5.1; MSIE 6.0)";
var stream = client.OpenRead(rpcURL);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
string s = sr.ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

I know I need to create a variable to increment the end "page_num=NUMBER" part--but I need to increment that by +1 UNTIL the stream reader reads "No records found" EXACTLY.

Any suggestions on an elegant way to do this? I know that *basically* I'll need to do an if/then statement with an increment +1 counter, but that's about all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with a simple `while` loop. Assuming the `StreamReader` is expected to return the exact string `No records found`, you could use something similar to the following.

```cs
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; Windows NT 5.1; MSIE 6.0)";

string rpcURL;
string s = '';
int page = 0;
while (s != 'No records found') {
    rpcURL = "https://api.myWebsite.com/urlrpc?method=getPlacementReport&username=" + userName + "&password=" + passWord + "&class_code=" + classCode + "&from_date=" + startDate + "&to_date=" + endDate + "&page_num=" + page;
    Console.WriteLine(rpcURL);
    using(var stream = client.OpenRead(rpcURL)) // both Stream and StreamReader
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(stream))    // need to be disposed.
    {
        s = sr.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine(s);
    } 
    page++;
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, this works like a charm. Getting some wrong header errors on subsequent page numbers (2, 3, ++) so it's not returning data, but I think that's a completely different issue. Thanks so much!

Comment: Just an update: had to put my Header.Add for the Webclient into the while statement, then all worked fine. Thanks again!